# Any way to Have Different Brightness Levels for Different Virtual Desktops

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, xcode, settings

As the title mentions, I'm looking for a way to have different brightness settings for the internal virtual desktops on macOS. It seems like an odd request, but it's extremely useful for when dealing with apps that fully support dark mode then switching to ones that don't.

I use Xcode in with dark mode theme and rank the brightness to the max and it looks absolutely gorgeous and allows me to work all throughout the night.
The issue is when switching to Safari to google search something and immediately get blinded by the bright white backgrounds of webpages. Currently I manually adjust the brightness every time I switch to the desktop with Safari and other apps that don't support darkmode.

Let me know if this is possible, I highly doubt it as I couldn't manage to find anything, but would love to hear what possible options are available. I'm comfortable with coding, if it means getting the result through terminal or python.